# Table in Entity Core Framework is emtpty

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Using the code first approach entity core framework is filling my table Show, however the table Cast is not filled.

The the table show is filled in my Database however the table cast is empthy and using the code first approach MSSQL creates another table.

Why is my table Cast empthy?

```cs
public class TvMazeContext : DbContext
{
    public TvMazeContext(DbContextOptions<TvMazeContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Show> shows { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Cast> casts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Show>().ToTable("Show");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Cast>().ToTable("Cast") ;          
    }
}
```

Here my DB intialize (edited)

```cs
public static class DbInitializer
{
    static List<List<Cast>> listedCasts = new List<List<Cast>>();
    static List<Show> listedShows = new List<Show>();
    public static async Task InitializeAsync(TvMazeContext context)
    {
        for (long i= 1;i < 10; i++)
        {
            long ShowId = i;
            Show show = await Crawler.CrawlShowAsync(ShowId);
            listedShows.Add(show);
            List<CastTemp> tempCasts = await Crawler.GetCastsAsync(ShowId);
            List<Cast> casts = CastTemp.TempCastToCast(tempCasts, ShowId);
            listedCasts.Add(casts); 
        }
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();

        if (context.shows.Any())
        {
            return;   // DB has been seeded
        }

        
        foreach (Show s in listedShows)
        {
            await context.shows.AddAsync(s);
            
        }
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();


        foreach (List<Cast> castsList in listedCasts)
        {
            foreach(Cast cast in castsList)
            {
                await context.casts.AddAsync(cast);
                
            }
        }
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();

    }
}
```

```cs
public class Cast
{

    
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long CastId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("birthday")]
    public string Birthday { get; set; }

    public long ShowId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Show> Show { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class Show
{        
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long ShowId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Cast> Casts { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class CastTemp
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long CastId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("birthday")]
    public string Birthday { get; set; }

    public static List<Cast> TempCastToCast(List<CastTemp> obj, long showId)
    {
        List<Cast> listedCasts = new List<Cast>();
        foreach (CastTemp temp in obj)
        {
            Cast output = new Cast() { CastId = temp.CastId, Name = temp.Name, Birthday = temp.Birthday, ShowId = showId };
            listedCasts.Add(output);
        }            
        return listedCasts;
    }
}
```

```cs
public class Crawler
{
    public static async Task<Show> CrawlShowAsync(long ShowId)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string url = "https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/" + ShowId;
        string response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
        var Show = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Show>(response);
        return Show;
    }
    public static async Task<List<CastTemp>> GetCastsAsync(long ShowId)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string urlcast = "https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/" + ShowId + "/cast";
        string responseCast = await client.GetStringAsync(urlcast);
        List<CastTemp> Casts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CastTemp>>(responseCast);
        return Casts;
    }
}
```

The crawler is working: I have debugged and seen that `listedCasts.Add(casts);` does add the casts to the list.
However they are not stored in the table Cast in my database: the for columns all have null

And Entity Core Framework itself created the named CastShow table bellow I think which also has only null values
[Table CastShow created by code first approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWysZ.png)

[Table Cast which is also null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtF3w.png)

[Table Show which has values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jj10u.png)

I also added program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
ConfigurationManager configuration = builder.Configuration;

//Database
builder.Services.AddDbContext<TvMazeContext>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddMvcCore().AddRazorViewEngine();

var app = builder.Build();

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
    try
    {
        TvMazeContext dbcontext = (TvMazeContext)scope.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(TvMazeContext));
        await DbInitializer.InitializeAsync(dbcontext);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var Logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<TvMazeContext>>();
        Logger.LogError(ex, "An error occured creating the DB");
    }

}

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `CastTemp` Model, You use `[JsonProperty("xx")]` attribute to bind value from Json, But in `https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/xxx/cast` page, `person` is a nested Json, If you use `[JsonProperty("id")]` to bind `id` in `person` directly, It will not bind anything. So you can change your code like:

```
public class Person
    {
        [JsonProperty("person")]
        public CastTemp castTemp { get; set; }
    }

public class Crawler
    {
        //..........
        public static async Task<List<CastTemp>> GetCastsAsync(long ShowId)
        {
            List<CastTemp> Casts = new List<CastTemp>();
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            string urlcast = "https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/" + ShowId + "/cast";
            string responseCast = await client.GetStringAsync(urlcast);
            List<Person> result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(responseCast);
            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                Casts.Add(item.castTemp);
            }
            return Casts;
        }
    }
```

**Note:**  There are some duplicate data in the `listedCasts`, you should remove the duplicate data when you insert it into the database

```
foreach (List<Cast> castsList in listedCasts)
            {
                foreach (Cast cast in castsList.DistinctBy(x=>x.CastId))
                {                        
                    await context.casts.AddAsync(cast);
                }
            }
```

Now, Data can be inserted into database successfully.

[image]

**Edit**

[image]

Comment: @Xiran I am not getting this result the database is still empthy. Does entity core framework also create a table  `CastShow`?

Comment: yes, Because they are many to many relationship. The Cast table does not allow empty columns by default, Some record's  birthday property are null, you can try to edit the database to make birthday column allow null then try again

Comment: @ozkanreyes , Have you mark birthday column allow null?

Comment: Yes I fixed it by using `public string? Birthday { get; set; }` Thanks!